# Google Speech to Text not working with large files

Tags: java, android, google-speech-api

I am trying to convert an audio file into text using Google speech api. If audio is 30 sec or less its working fine, but when audio file is longer then 30 seconds then its not converting audio file into text.

please help me, what should i do?

Comment: have you tried using [asynchronous speech recognition](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/async-recognize)?

Answer (score 2):

You should use asynchronous speech recognition, and also upload the audio file to Google Cloud Storage.
Here the [audio limit](https://cloud.google.com/speech/quotas) of Speech API